# Created Custom File Downloads. MD5 Hash Doesn't Match

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, download

Using Asp.Net MVC I was creating a file downloader. The problem with the built in Asp.Net MVC functions is that they don't work on extremely large file downloads and in some browsers they don't pop up the save-as dialog. So I rolled by own using an article from msdn http://support.microsoft.com/kb/812406. The problem now is that the files are downloading perfectly, but the MD5 Checksums aren't matching because the file size is slightly different on the server than the download (even though 1000 tests show that the downloads execute just fine). Here is the code:

```
public class CustomFileResult : ActionResult
{
    public string File { get; set; }

    public CustomFileResult(string file)
    {
        this.File = file;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        Stream iStream = null;

        // Buffer to read 10K bytes in chunk:
        byte[] buffer = new Byte[10000];

        // Length of the file:
        int length;

        // Total bytes to read:
        long dataToRead;

        // Identify the file name.
        string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(this.File);

        try
        {
            // Open the file.
            iStream = new System.IO.FileStream(this.File, System.IO.FileMode.Open,
                        System.IO.FileAccess.Read, System.IO.FileShare.Read);


            // Total bytes to read:
            dataToRead = iStream.Length;

            context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
            context.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);

            // Read the bytes.
            while (dataToRead > 0)
            {
                // Verify that the client is connected.
                if (context.HttpContext.Response.IsClientConnected)
                {
                    // Read the data in buffer.
                    length = iStream.Read(buffer, 0, 10000);

                    // Write the data to the current output stream.
                    context.HttpContext.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, length);

                    // Flush the data to the HTML output.
                    context.HttpContext.Response.Flush();

                    buffer = new Byte[10000];
                    dataToRead = dataToRead - length;
                }
                else
                {
                    //prevent infinite loop if user disconnects
                    dataToRead = -1;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Trap the error, if any.
            context.HttpContext.Response.Write("Error : " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (iStream != null)
            {
                //Close the file.
                iStream.Close();
            }
            context.HttpContext.Response.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

And the execution:

```
return new CustomFileResult(file.FullName);
```

Comment: You don't need to re-initialize `buffer` every time.  Also, use `break;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the issue was a missing header.

```
context.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", iStream.Length.ToString());
```

Adding that header solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the

```
Response.TransmitFile(string fileName)
```

method.

It's really good and has some things to avoid OutOfMemory expections as well.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12s31dhy(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Once starting to write to the OutputStream, try flushing the OutputStream itself instead of flushing the response:
`context.HttpContext.Response.OutputStream.Flush()`

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is here:

```
length = iStream.Read(buffer, 0, 10000);

// Write the data to the current output stream.
context.HttpContext.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, length);
```

Every loop you read into a buffer of exactly 10,000 bytes and write that to stream.  That means every file that someone downloads will be in multiples of 10,000.  So if I was to download a file that is 9,998 bytes from your site, the file I got would be 10,000 bytes.  Meaning that the hash would never match.  My file would have 2 null bytes at the end of it.

You need to add a check to make sure that the amount of data to read is >=10k, and if it is not, resize your byte to the exact amount that is left, and transmit that.  that should fix the hash mismatch

try something like this:

```
if (context.HttpContext.Response.IsClientConnected)
{
 // Read the data in buffer.
 if (dataToRead>=10000)
 {
   byte[] buffer = new byte[10000];
   length = 10000
   context.HttpContext.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, length);
 }
 else
 {
   byte[] buffer = new byte[dataToRead];
   length = buffer.Length;
   context.HttpContext.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, length);  
 }
 // Flush the data to the HTML output.
 context.HttpContext.Response.Flush();

 dataToRead = dataToRead - length;
}
```

Comment: iStream.Read will return how many bytes it read. the last read will be less then 10,000. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.read.aspx

Comment: 10,000 is the *max* number of bytes to be read.  He is storing the actual number of bytes in the length variable.

Comment: @Dana, The Scrum Meister - you are both absolutely right.  I misread that he was storing the number of bytes read in a variable.  That'll teach me to not read carefully.